# Can Qt Remote Objects be used to share an entire mainwindow UI?

Tags: c++, qt, qtremoteobjects

I'm currently looking into Qt RO as a possible solution for my current need to remotely access a UI without using Qt WebGL. I am having trouble finding any good example uses of Qt RO outside of the starter ones in the qt docs.

Will Qt RO fit my needs and does anyone know of a good example?

Comment: Have you tried out the starter ones?

Comment: @LászlóPapp if you mean the ones here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-gettingstarted.html

Then yes and so far I can only figure out how to use basic data types and not anything that has inheritance as a property.

Comment: What do you mean by basic data types?

Comment: I mean only int, string, boolean, etc. Repc can't seem to handle anything with inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom types work just fine with Qt Remote Objects. Just like with any other meta object compiler issue in Nuke, you just need to make sure that the type is known to the meta object compiler.

So, for example, you will need to register it.

> PROP(SomeOtherType myCustomType)     // Custom types work. Needs
> #include for the
> // appropriate header for your type, make
> // sure your type is known to the metabject
> // system, and make sure it supports Queued
> // Connections (see Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and
> // qRegisterMetaType)
>
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtremoteobjects-repc.html#prop

You can also find more information about how to handle custom types in Qt in general [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/custom-types.html). You would register your type like this:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Message);
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/custom-types.html